# Browser default notification

Tags: browser, notifications

Is there way to popup notification in browser without using any plugging?

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>

        <script>
        function notifyMe() {
          // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
          if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
          }

          // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
          else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            // If it's okay let's create a notification
            var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
          }

          // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
          else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
              // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
              if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
              }
            });
          }

        }
        </script>
```